# How do I search for hardcoded 800 numbers amongst thousands of pages?

Tags: regex, phone-number

I need to look amongst thousands of files for 800 numbers that may have been hardcoded into some code. I'm a novice at regular expressions but I thought they might be useful in this case. I was able to find this online:

```
^(\+?1)?(8(00|44|55|66|77|88)[2-9]\d{6})$
```

Unfortunately I don't think this would take into account different formats such as:

- `1(800) 765-4321`
- `1 877 765-4321`
- `1-855-765-4321`
- `1.800.765.4321`

I don't know how varied the phone numbers can be, but I do think there should be a catch-all way to write this.

Comment: A lot of good answers. It's too bad I can only pick one. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matches all of your demo data and also matches only numbers, such as `18001234321`

```
\+?1?\D*\d\d\d\D*\d\d\d\D*\d\d\d\d\b
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/jsMk6ixX_evpOaSp)

You can also see its technical description at the bottom of this page: http://regex101.com/r/lE2fR2

Basically, its zero-or-more non-digits (`\D`) followed by some digits (`\d`).

For 800 numbers, just change the first `\d` to an `8`.

If your goal is to strip out everything but the numbers, then capture the numbers and replace with the capture groups:

```
Find what:  \+?(1?)\D*(\d\d\d)\D*(\d\d\d)\D*(\d\d\d\d)\b
Replace with:  $1$2$3$4
```

Java:

```
import  java.util.regex.Pattern;
import  java.util.regex.Matcher;

/**
   <P>{@code java StripPhoneFormattingXmpl}</P>
 **/
public class StripPhoneFormattingXmpl  {
   public static final void main(String[] igno_red)  {


      String sToSearch = "1(800) 765-4321 1 877 765-4321 1-855-765-4321 1.800.765.4321 18001231234";

      String sRegex = "\\+?(1?)\\D*(\\d\\d\\d)\\D*(\\d\\d\\d)\\D*(\\d\\d\\d\\d)\\b";
      String sRplcWith = "$1$2$3$4";

      Matcher m = Pattern.compile(sRegex).matcher(sToSearch);
      StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
      while(m.find())  {
         m.appendReplacement(sb, sRplcWith);
      }
      m.appendTail(sb);

      System.out.println("Original: " + sToSearch);
      System.out.println("Stripped: " + sb);
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java StripPhoneFormattingXmpl
Original: 1(800) 765-4321 1 877 765-4321 1-855-765-4321 1.800.765.4321 18001231234
Stripped: 18007654321 18777654321 18557654321 18007654321 18001231234
```

Comment: This is elegant and simple. It might catch more than I want, but for my purposes, I'd rather catch too much than too little. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: updated answer (see comments)

How about this:

```
(\d\D{0,2}8\d{2}\D{0,2}\d{3}\D{0,2}\d{4})
```

[See it in action.](http://regex101.com/r/oX6tF0)

Matches:

```
1 (800) 765 4321
1 877 765-4321
1-855-765-4321
1.800.765.4321
1 (800) 123-4567
18007654321
```

Very similar to aliteralmind's but a bit shorter. The `{}` allow you to say that:

```
z{x}     #you want exactly x matches of z
z{x,y}   #you want between x and y matches of z
```

So:

```
a{3,6}  #you want between 3 and 6 repeats of a
```

Comment: Might want to allow `0` non-digit characters, so that `18007654321` will be considered a match.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use, according to your own regex:

```
(?:^|\D)(?:\+?1)?\D*8([04-8])\1\D*[2-9]\d\d\D*\d{4}\b
```

Comment: The OP states that the numbers are hard-coded into existing code, in which case it is likely that the anchors should be removed. Also, I think `\dd` is a typo and should be `\d\d`. With these two changes, it does match all of his phone numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a somewhat complicated regex that will filter out invalid patterns, but still keep the ones you've listed.

For example, it will NOT accept numbers like:

- `1-801-765-1234`
- `1-800-123-4567`
- `1ABCDEFGHIJK8007654321`
- `+1 877765-4321`
- `1.800-765.4321`

`(+?\b1|\b)((()|([.-])|\s)?8(00|44|55|66|77|88)(?(3))|)(?(4)\4|(?(2)\s|))[2-9]\d{2}(?(4)\4|(?(2)[.-]|))\d{4}\b`

It will ensure the following:

1. Only 800, 844, 855, 866, 877, and 888 numbers are accepted
2. The NXX must start with [2-9]
3. Only the following delimiters can be used [ .-]
4. If our format has a delimiter in the beginning (e.g. 1-800...), only that same delimiter can be used for the rest of the number.
5. If our format does not have a delimiter in the beginning (e.g "1(800)" or "1 800"), then no delimiter appears between the 8XX and the NXX.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

See [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/SJXiFHiRtm0e0hpI) for a commented version that breaks down what each part does.

Comment: This Debuggex program is pretty powerful, it really clarifies things.

Comment: Yes, [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/) is a very nice tool for testing regular expressions and visualizing them.  I figured the comments were best left there, as they make the regex much longer.